# Why don't my frame titles update?

Tags: osx, frame-parameters, frame-title-format

I run Emacs 27.1 on my MacOS MBP and use `desktop-mode`.

After starting emacs (with frames re-created by the desktop restore), the frame titles are wrong and seem to remain wrong until I do something like evaluate `(set-for 0)` in each frame.

Anyone know why that happens?

My `frame-title-format` has value `"%b"`. I don't explicitly set the frame parameter `name`.

GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, NS appkit-1894.60 Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021))
of 2020-08-18

Comment: Maybe you can show a minimal bit of code and recipe using it, to repro the problem starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)? Otherwise, we have to guess whatever else you might be doing that might lead to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot the backtick (`)

```
 (setq-default frame-title-format `("%b"))
```